# Running a specific spring batch job amongst several jobs contained withing a spring boot fat jar

Tags: java, jar, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to run a spring batch job from a spring boot fat jar and I am having issues referencing the nested jars.

Here is the command I use:

```
java -cp bignibou-batch-core/build/libs/bignibou-batch-core.jar:lib/spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner com.bignibou.batch.configuration.BatchConfiguration mailingJob
```

Notice how I reference the nested spring batch jar using the colon. Why is this not working?

It says it cannot find the main class:

```
Erreur : impossible de trouver ou charger la classe principale org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner
```

Comment: Check that "lib/spring-batch-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar" is not missing.

Comment: Thanks it is not missing...

Comment: Why are you trying to refer to the spring batch jar as the executable jar?  You should just be using: `java -jar bignibou-batch-core/build/libs/bignibou-batch-core.jar`...

Comment: Thank Michael: the reason I want to use the command line runner is that I am going to have several batch jobs within the same fat jar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I turns out that there is a nice option to choose one job (out of multiple jobs) from within a fat jar:

```
--spring.batch.job.names=jobOne,jobThree
```

Only `jobOne` & `jobThree` will run even if `jobTwo` also exists.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-batch-applications.html for documentation.

So as far as I am concerned, this sorted my problem:

```
java -jar bignibou-batch-core/build/libs/bignibou-batch-core.jar --spring.batch.job.names=mailingJob
```

Comment: finally something simple that the client can use easily